# Variable image aspect ratios in a square box

Tags: html, css

I have a database for house listings with images of the homes for each entry. The images are uploaded by a 3rd party and they send images in random widths and lengths. Some are square-ish, some are portrait, some are landscape, etc. Without using javascript, what would be the best way to have the image completely fill a square div that is a definite size (200px by 200px, for example). I think using the image as a background image of each div and using "display: cover" would work great but not sure of any browser compatibility issues or maybe there is a better way. any suggestions?

Comment: if you use images with varying size then the images will pixelate, its better to have some back-end code to process the images so that they come in same size before you show them in html... think about it

Comment: Don't worry about browser compatibility on `background-size: cover;` (not `display`, by the way, that's a different thing). Apart from IE10 and below, it's very widely supported (http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size), and on top of that, the older browsers will still display it, just cut off, so they get a similar experience of lower quality (which should sput them to get better browsers). For old browsers you could maybe place the image inside the div and scale it (`max-height:100%;max-width:100%;`) and add the rule `position:absolute;left:calc(-9999px)` to hide image on new browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If compatibility is what you care about, this is the best way to give everyone a decent experience:

```css
div {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: calc(-2000px);
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x150)">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" />
</div>
```

Basically, use background-size to scale where available, and show the image to all browsers that don't support `calc`. Two birds, one stone.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but I prefer using [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), which is supported by all major browsers except IE. If you need a solution that works for IE and Edge, you can check out [how to implement a fallback](https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3#.qypy5kboi), or fall back to using `background-size: cover`.

Comment: Hotdangety, that one snuck up on me. Never heard of `object-fit` before let alone it's decent compatibility. Awesome!

Answer (score -1):

Avoid explicitly defining the images' size. Instead use this:

```
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ya50143r/)

**OR** if you want to use `background-image` then center it using:

```
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
```

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c2y5uety/)

Comment: This is useful... If the question wasn't about how to _fill a box with the image_ instead of _fit the image to the box_. There are legitimate use cases for wanting an image to be 200x200 pixels.

Comment: using `background-image` is bad for SEO check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542606/background-images-and-seo)

Comment: Yes, how exactly does that make you solution a valid solution though, it did not solve the problem. My proposed solution above does _both_.

Comment: I'm sure no one likes a cropped image on their website...it has to be scaled or aspect-ratio changed or worse, cropped.

Comment: What? What are you talking about? People dislike changed aspect ratios _more_ than they dislike a cropped photo... Also, your solution is sort-of used in my answer as a fallback for older browsers. Newer browsers and the `contain` value for backgrounds allow for pretty decent digitised crops.

Comment: having the image cropped in my case is preferred as the only other option would be to have whitespace or bars on either side of an image that doesn't have the correct aspect ratio. I should have specified that the image is a thumbnail and brings the user to a more detailed page of the property, which displays the full image